# Error "Timed out waiting for the socket to be ready for a write" while connecting to server in Xcode

Tags: ios, websocket, starscream

I am trying to connect to server for web socket connection. but I am getting the error:

> "Websocket is disconnected: Optional(Starscream.WSError(type:
>   Starscream.ErrorType.writeTimeoutError, message: \"Timed out waiting
>   for the socket to be ready for a write\", code: 0))"
>
> Starscream.WSError(type: Starscream.ErrorType.writeTimeoutError

How can I solve it? also 
Here is my source code link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v348vxxjf74dsds/websocket.zip?dl=0

I tried to connect after some time again too, Once its failed but still it's giving me same error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, it's working fine. the only change I have made is your socket server URL

before it was  `ws://192.168.1.2:8080`

and I have updated with `"http://192.168.1.41:8080"` //41 is my IP. you can use yours

just changed `ws` with `http`.

Comment: I have tried with http. getting same error may issue is with my server script. can you share me your server side code ? Thanks.

Comment: sure, here it is. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HIjS83-uyf3tlxEmXf5rTYptQdh_LFES?usp=sharing

Comment: I have also added a video for your reference.

Comment: Please accept this answer if this solved your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the video but i am not able to access the your video please provide permission.

Comment: here is my server side code link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fc6bnqmwu9v3gk/server.php?dl=0

Comment: please try again that link. it's available publically now.

Comment: I checked the file and video. It seems my server code is different. I am unable to run your server code because there is no library of web socket. Can you allow access of it.

Comment: my code is in Node JS. please execute it with `node app.js` command.

Comment: I tried with setup of node and tested with Firechamp its working but not with my code so still i am missing something. will firewall block the connection ?

Comment: your iOS code is working properly with my node JS server. I really can't say what wrong at your place.